# Instead of renaming my file just duplicating

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream, outputstream

I have a program that should process the files in the directory and if the file size is more than 50 bytes delete it. Otherwise, if the file size is less then 50 bytes program should rename the args[1] file to the allFilesContent.txt(same directory), and write all the files to this file, separated by "n" (110 ASCII code). But instead the program just creates another file and writes to the very first args[1] file. What's the problem?

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        File path = new File(args[0]);
        File resultFileAbsolutePath = new File(args[1]);
        ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean isRenamed = false;

        for(File file : path.listFiles())
        {
            if(file.length() > 50)
            {
                FileUtils.deleteFile(file);
            }

            else if(file.length() <= 50)
            {
                if(!isRenamed)
                {
                FileUtils.renameFile(resultFileAbsolutePath, new File(resultFileAbsolutePath.getParent()+"\\allFilesContent.txt"));
                isRenamed = true;
                }
                if(!file.getName().equals(resultFileAbsolutePath.getName()))
                {
                allFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(allFiles, new Comparator<File>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2)
            {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(resultFileAbsolutePath, true);

        for (File file : allFiles)
        {
            try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file))
            {
                if(allFiles.indexOf(file) != 0) fileOutputStream.write(110);
                int data;
                while(fileInputStream.available() > 0)
                {
                    data = fileInputStream.read();
                    fileOutputStream.write(data);
                }
            }
        }

       fileOutputStream.close();
    }

    public static void deleteFile(File file)
    {
        if (!file.delete())
        {
            System.out.println("Can not delete file with name " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And FileUtils class

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileUtils
{

    public static void deleteFile(File file)
    {
        if (!file.delete())
        {
            System.out.println("Can not delete file with name " + file.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void renameFile(File source, File destination)
    {
        if (!source.renameTo(destination))
        {
            System.out.println("Can not rename file with name " + source.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have following statement: "FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(resultFileAbsolutePath, true);"

Instead of "true" put "false". It should work.

Comment: No, that just allows the outputstream write from multiple files